# Objective-C: using methods from other files

Tags: objective-c, file, methods

I have looked at all the other people who had this error pop up, and I know it is a pathing error, and yes I have tried to quit and reboot it, I checked the paths were using up-to-date files, and most of what people suggested with no success. I am trying to get methods from TapViewController to run in JumpController. I simplified the method I want to be called to make it easier to find the issue, but still am having trouble. Here is the relevant code I have so far:

TapViewController.h

```
-(void)hello;
```

TapViewController.m

```
-(void)hello {
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}
```

JumpController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import 'TapViewController.h'

@property (strong, nonatomic) TapViewController *TapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) JumpController *JumpControl;
```

JumpController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     self.JumpControl = (TapViewController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
     self.TapView = [[TapViewController alloc] init];
     [self.JumpControl.TapView hello];
}
```

I grabbed most of this code from what others have said to do, so I don't really know if some of it is irrelevant or if all will help in the situation. Basically, the app crashes when it loads stating `[AppDelegate TapView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...`. Let me know if I am doing anything wrong or if I left out relevant code!

**UPDATE:** Using what others have said and from my own personal changes, It seems like the problem is not only with `self.JumpControl = (TapViewController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate` but also with `self.JumpControl` as a whole. Because I created the `TapViewController *TapView` in the `.h` file there is no reason to use `self.JumpControl` which caused problems on the order of views that showed up. I will mark *almas* as correct, but I wanted to clarify what more needed to be done.

Comment: This does not solve the system. But for a start you could rename all properties too begin with a lowercase letter. `self.jumpControl`

Comment: is TapViewController a sublcass of UIApplicationDelegate? I doubt.

Comment: When do you set `self.jumpControl.tapView`? As far as we can see, it is most probably nil by the time when you call hello on that object. And in Obj-C you can send messages (call methods) to nil. Try `self.jumpControl setTapView (self.tapView)` before calling it or call `[self.tapView hello]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here: `"self.JumpControl = (TapViewController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;"`. You are trying to cast your AppDelegate to TapViewController, thats why it crashes. AppDelegate is not a view controller. Your error message `[AppDelegate TapView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` clearly states that AppDelegate doesn't recognize the method "TapView", it is because app delegate is not an instance of "TapViewController".

Comment: so after I get rid of it, I receive a message saying _"Warning: Attempt to present <JumpController:... > on <TapViewController: ...> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!_ (yes there was an exclamation point). Do you have any ideas on how to change this?

Comment: Can you publish your app on github and provide a link so i can take a look at what you are trying to do?

Comment: Unfortunately it is a private project, but currently I am just trying to log "Hello" when Jump Controller loads and go from there once that works.